# Do all shots count for XP gain?

Tags: killing-floor-2

In KF2 XP is given a lot differently to the first game, so damage seems to earn you XP.

Unlike the first game I've seen people aim away from heavy enemies like a Scrake or Fleshpound and attack clots, so does all weapon damage to an enemy give XP?  I am including pistol damage in that, even for heavy enemies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes any damaging shot gets you XP when the zed dies.

There are good reasons for not raging Scakes and Fleshpounds if you can't handle them yourself or the team isn't ready - it doesn't have to be about XP. Or perhaps they're just scared of trying?

Fun fact - You get XP for the class your damaging weapon is for, regardless of what class you currently are. So a Berserker who shoots zeds with an RPG will get +Demo XP for them.